# Opening Pages in New Window

Tags: xhtml, standards-compliance

Is there a way to open a page in XHTML without using `<a href="page.html" target="_blank">` that is standards compliant?

I'm not using frames, but there are some pages that I want to open in a new window instead of the current one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's window.open() method. However this could easily be blocked by a pop-up blocker. Why do you not want to use the "_blank" target?

Comment: It's not standards compliant with XHTML Strict. That won't stop me from using it, but if there's a method that is standards compliant, then it's probably better to use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<a href="page.html" rel="external">My Page</a>
```

And then you run this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel="external"]').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

This will add the `target="blank"` to the links and make your HTML validate :)

Answer (score 0):

Most pop-up blockers wont block a pop up that has been requested by the user e.g you click a link and it pops up a window. IF you add an onlick event to your link and a target, the desired effect will work even if JS is turned off although you don't want to use target="_blank"